# class в json на языке python

Tags: python, json

Как преобразовать `class` в `json`?

В [стандартном](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) я не увидел.

Comment: Под struct вы вот это имеете в виду: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/struct.html ?

Comment: Не плохо было бы привести пример Вашего struct

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич пардон, я имел ввиду классы. Я пишу на golang и python. Поэтому путаюсь

Comment: @insolor нет, класс

Comment: посмотрите лучше на pickle, работает точно также как json но почти со всеми объектами.

Comment: @AndrioSkur pickle плох тем, что он оказывается не пригодным для внешного использования. Этот пакет станет непригодным, если поля класса изменились.

Comment: Какого плана классы вы хотите сериализовать? Кто будет потом потреблять результат?

Comment: @jfs Считайте, что я отправляю его на сервер

Comment: @hedgehogues какие данные ваш сервер принимает? Что у вас на входе (приведите пример класса) и в каком точно виде вы хотите его на сервере увидеть (что на выходе: явно укажите json текст)

Comment: @jfs какая разница как? json и json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение в лоб:

```
# Для python2 нужно class A(object):
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
        self.c = 3
        self.items = [4, 5, 6]

    def to_dict(self):
        fields = {
            'a': self.a,
            'b': self.b,
            'c': self.c,
            'items': self.items,
        }

        # Если порядок полей важен, нужно использовать OrderedDict
        # from collections import OrderedDict
        # fields = OrderedDict()
        # fields['a'] = self.a
        # fields['b'] = self.b
        # fields['c'] = self.c
        # fields['items'] = self.items

        return fields


a = A()

import json
print(json.dumps(a.to_dict(), ensure_ascii=False, indent=4))
```

Консоль:

```
{
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "items": [
        4,
        5,
        6
    ],
    "c": 3
}
```

Более хитрым вариантом будет написание функции, которая сама проанализирует атрибуты класса (поля) и составит словарь с нужными полями и их значениями.

---

Ответ `Михаил Алексеевич` натолкнул на мысль о написании такой функции и вот что получилось:

```
class SubField:
    def __init__(self):
        self.flag = True


class Field:
    def __init__(self, tag1, tag2, sub_field_flag=True):
        self.tag1 = tag1
        self.tag2 = tag2

        self.sub_field = SubField()
        self.sub_field.flag = sub_field_flag


class Object:
    a = 0
    b = '123'

    def __init__(self):
        self.c = 3
        self.items = [1, 2, 3, 4]
        self.maps = {
            'is': True,
            'not': 0,
        }

        self.field = Field('abc', 'tag2')
        self.field_2 = Field(777, False, sub_field_flag=False)


def object_to_dict(object):
    fields = dict()
    fields.update(object.__class__.__dict__)
    fields.update(object.__dict__)

    fields = dict(filter(lambda x: not x[0].startswith('_'), fields.items()))

    new_fields = dict()
    for k, v in fields.items():
        if hasattr(v, '__dict__'):
            v = object_to_dict(v)

        new_fields[k] = v

    return new_fields


if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj = Object()
    fields = object_to_dict(obj)
    print(fields)
    print()

    import json
    print(json.dumps(fields, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

Консоль:

```
{'items': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'c': 3, 'maps': {'not': 0, 'is': True}, 'b': '123', 'field_2': {'tag2': False, 'sub_field': {'flag': False}, 'tag1': 777}, 'field': {'tag2': 'tag2', 'sub_field': {'flag': True}, 'tag1': 'abc'}, 'a': 0}

{
    "a": 0,
    "b": "123",
    "c": 3,
    "field": {
        "sub_field": {
            "flag": true
        },
        "tag1": "abc",
        "tag2": "tag2"
    },
    "field_2": {
        "sub_field": {
            "flag": false
        },
        "tag1": 777,
        "tag2": false
    },
    "items": [
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4
    ],
    "maps": {
        "is": true,
        "not": 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Аналогично... угу

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич, ммм?

Comment: тремя минутами ранее написал почти то же :)

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич, когда я начал писать вашего ответа еще не было и я его увидел уже после отправки своего. Ваш пример работает только при указании атрибутов в типе, а у меня и в типе, и в объекте

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич, вот теперь можно говорить "про почти тоже самое" :)

Comment: скрытые атрибуты уже можно не дампить?)

Comment: @AndrioSkur, скрытые атрибуты обычно для внутренного использования объектов нужны, да и среди них магические методы попадаются, вот и посчитал что можно их не дампить

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос, так как предлагается частное решение задачи, а постановка вопроса - общая.

Answer (score 5):

Можно *class* преобразовать в *dict*, а затем из *dict* получить *json*:

```
import json

class test:
  a = int(0)
  b = str('123')

test_dict= test.__dict__
test_json = json.dumps(test_dict)
print (test_json)
```

> `{"a": 0, "__module__": "__main__", "b": "123", "__doc__": null}`

Comment: Лучше от объекта класса показать: `t = Test(); test_dict = t.__dict__; test_json = json.dumps(test_dict)`